# neo4jphp relateTo() to a getResultSet() object

Tags: neo4jphp

I'm using the Neo4jphp REST API and I'm having a problem of relating a node iv created in my code to a node im retrieving from the neo4j database.
I'm retrieving the node as follows

`$querystring="MATCH(n)"."WHERE has (n.name) and n.name='Interests'"."RETURN n";
         $query=new Everyman\Neo4j\Cypher\Query($client,$querystring);
         $result=$query->getResultSet();`

im creating another node in my code using createNode()
`$friend=$client->makeNode()->setProperty('name',$fname)->save();`

I used relateTo() to relate them

```
$m=$client->getNode($result);
$m->relateTo($friend,$movi)->save();//$movi is a common movie name
```

but getting this error

```
PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class Everyman\\Neo4j\\Query\\ResultSet could not be converted to string in /var/www/vendor/everyman/neo4jphp/lib/Everyman/Neo4j/Cache/EntityCache.php
```

would really appreciate any input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A neo4jphp query returns a row object (even if theres only one responce) so

```
$m=$client->getNode($result);
```

won't work

try this instead

```
$querystring="MATCH(n) WHERE has (n.name) and n.name='Interests' RETURN n";
$query=new Everyman\Neo4j\Cypher\Query($client,$querystring);
$result=$query->getResultSet();
foreach($result as $resultItem)
{
   $resultArray[] = $resultItem['x'];
   //$resultItem['x'] is the node object, now $result array is an array of node objects
}
$friend= $client->makeNode()->setProperty('name',$fname)->save();
$resultArray[0]->relateTo($friend,$movi)->save();
```

this code will also work with this query (easier to read)

```
$querystring="MATCH (n {name:"Interests"}) RETURN n";
```

Comment: Thank you.it's work for me when retrieve one property.how this work with when return associative array?

Comment: @IshaS If your query returns whole nodes the `$resultArray` will be an array of Node objects, if you want to return an array with associative arrays of the data instead you can use `$resultArray[] = $resultItem['x']->getProperties();` in the foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```php
$queryString = "MATCH(n) WHERE has (n.name) and n.name= {name} RETURN ID(n)";
$query = new Everyman\Neo4j\Cypher\Query($client,$queryString,array('name'=>'Interests'));

$result = $query->getResultSet();

$resultArray=array();
foreach($result as $row)
{
    array_push($resultArray,$row['n']);
}

$friend = $client->getNode($resultArray[0]);
$friend->relateTo($friend,$movi)-save();
```